# Chain rule in Banach(?) space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, chain-rule

I am a statistician punching above my weight on a problem involving functional analysis.

I am trying to write down conditions under which I am allowed to apply the chain rule to calculate a derivative of a composition of two functions $F \circ G$. In my problem $G: \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0} \rightarrow L^{\infty}$. The first (only?) part of my difficulties is I'm having a difficult time notating the codomain of $F$. The mapping $F$ can be described as $\psi \mapsto D(\psi)$ for an element $\psi \in L^{\infty}$, where $D(\psi)$ is an element of a Hilbert space $H(\psi)$ with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\psi}$ that depends on $\psi$.

To add some details about $H(\psi)$: the simplest case is to think of $\psi$ as a probability measure and $H(\psi)$ is the Hilbert space of functions $h$ (appropriately defined on some outcome space) such that $\int h d\psi = 0$ and $\int h^2 d\psi < \infty$, i.e., an $L^2_0(\psi)$ space. Ideally, I'd like to be able to handle slightly more complex cases than this, but this would suffice for now.

I am hoping to argue that the codomain of $F$ is a Banach space, in which case I think I can just assume $F$ and $G$ are Fréchet differentiable and voilá, chain rule. But I am getting hung up on the fact that each Hilbert space above is indexed by the particular $L^{\infty}$ element. So I don't really understand what metric to use in this space or whether indeed the codomain is at all a Banach space.

Again, I'm out of my depths here, so please let me know if I can clarify any elements of the problem.

Comment: It seems the difficulty you are having is about particular features of the codomain of the maps involved but you do not tell us what those maps are so it seems unlikely that anyone here can help you with the information provided. It even seems to me that what is written can't be quite right since you say that $F(\psi) \in H(\psi)$ but $G$ is a map on the reals so that it seems that $G \circ F$ shouldn't even be well-defined. I'd suggest you should tell us what those maps are.

Comment: Sorry, I had the composition backwards. $G$ maps a non-negative real number to a bounded measurable function; $F$ maps that function to an element of a Hilbert space with an inner product that depends on that function itself. The inner product in the Hilbert space is an integral wrt to a measure that depends on $\psi$. I could add in more details, but it's not clear to me which details in particular are important.

Comment: Can you give the definition of $H(\psi)$?

Comment: It sounds like you are mapping into a [vector bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) over $L^\infty$. You might be able to use the vector space structure of $L^\infty$ to create a natural isomorphism between each $H(\psi)$ and $H(0)$, which would allow you to treat $F$ as being into $H(0)$. But without knowing more about the $H(\psi)$, I cannot say for sure. In any case, you still have the issue of the inner product varying with $\psi$.

Comment: @Anne, I've added some more details about $H(\psi)$.

Comment: I think $F$ is not a map from $L^\infty$ to some fixed Banach space, but a section of your Hilbert bundle $\cup_{\psi\in L^\infty}H(\psi)\to L^\infty$ (or may be: replace everywere $L^\infty$ by the subset of probability density functions). I don't know the definition of the derivative of such a section.